How to remove screen light effect when using two VS Code theme extensions?
I like using synthwave, keeps me focus. Now I'm using two themes
Synthwave x Fluoromachine & epic animations and SynthWave '84 - VS Code theme simultaneously somehow. Don't ask me how, I don't understand json. Here are their respective themes json files from GitHub.

synthwave-x-fluoromachine.json
synthwave-color-theme.json

I want to keep Synthwave x Fluoromachine's dark purple/violet color scheme which is like this Dark but when I'm opening a file, it becomes like this Light. To those who know their json, how do I set files window like the first image? Please help, I have no idea which configuration I'm suppose to change. Thank you.
I attempted to use both VS Code theme extensions hoping they somehow work which they did. Now I want to keep it that way but with the files window being dark like the Synthwave x Fluoromachine's foreground color?

simultaneously somehow. Don't ask me how ... yet you state that I attempted to use both VS Code theme extensions hoping they somehow work which they did.  ... so, of course we don't need to ask you how, you did it deliberately :p

change the editor.backgroundColor by customizing the theme
